# PHP:How to use sql query result

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to use value of query.

Please look at this code :

```
//Anything goes here
........
$show="SELECT *FROM persons";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$show);
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>name</td><td>Firstname</td><td>Lastname</td><td>address</td><td>phone</td>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='mname' value=".$row[0]."></td>";
echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='single' value='edit'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
?>
<?
if (isset($_POST['single']))
{
$show="SELECT *FROM persons WHERE name='$_POST[mname]'";
//another sql query here
............
.............
```

However, It is not right coding.
I just want if user click on edit, then it will do specific command for every query. But here, after loop it will get only last row's `$row[0]` . 
How to do this: when user click on `edit` button beside every row then it will get only this row's value

Comment: Show us your query before while loop. Question is not asked properly.

Comment: You're running a different query that just returns _a_ specific result.

Comment: i enter that value into a form

Comment: means you want run the different queries in same page with `GET` or `POST` values. right?

Comment: yes. And for this i am using `form` . But my need is how to get the exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my code. page.php  is your current page

```
........
$show="SELECT *FROM persons";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$show);
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>name</td><td>Firstname</td><td>Lastname</td><td>address</td><td>phone</td>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='mname' value=".$row[0]."></td>";
echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='page.php?single=".$row[0]."'>edit</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
?>
<?
if (isset($_GET['single']))
{
$show="SELECT *FROM persons WHERE name='$_GET[single]'";
```

Comment: showing `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/.....`  which is the line of your new code `echo "<td><a href="page.php?single=$row[0]">edit</a></td>";`

Comment: try with updated answer

Comment: that's a nice and simple solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your code in if else condition like this:

```
// if form submitted then show edit form with selected person data
if (isset($_POST['single'])) {
    $show = "SELECT *FROM persons WHERE name='$_POST[mname]'";
//another sql query here
    ............
    .............
} else {
    $show = "SELECT *FROM persons";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $show);

    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>name</td><td>Firstname</td><td>Lastname</td><td>address</td><td>phone</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<form method='post'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='mname' value=" . $row[0] . "> <input type='hidden' name='id' value=" . $row[1] . "></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='single' value='edit'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
}
```

Also use hidden field in the form and keep record id in that field and use that in your query as it will precise the query and increases performance.
Another useful thing is that you should have a new form tag with each row, like I have used form tag in while loop, using this your code will only pass one person id,name to your edit page. While in your case it will be submitting whole data.

Comment: then which `$_POST[mname]` it will get after loop ? the last one ?
but it's need to get the value of selected.

Comment: See i have updated, you should use form tags in the while loop. You are not submitting one field only but all the input fields because in your table there will more then one row and as var name is $mname for all therefore it only gives you last $mname.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
//Anything goes here
........
$show="SELECT * FROM persons";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$show);
echo "<form method='post'>";
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>name</td><td>Firstname</td><td>Lastname</td><td>address</td><td>phone</td>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='mname' value='".$row[0]."'></td>";
echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[4]."</td>";
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='single' value='edit'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
?>
<?
if (isset($_POST['single']))
{
 $show="SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name='".$_POST[mname]."'";
  //another sql query here
   ............
   .............
```

Comment: actually it's get the value. but for looping it's get the last value instead of selected `edit` button.